# Can't run c program in other partition

Tags: permissions, mount, executable

I'm in dual boot with Windows, and i've created a shared ntfs partition.
I' ve cloned a project from github, use make to compile it but seems it isn't recognized as runnable. I've added the right permission and tried to change the owner of the directory.
This is the output of ls -l:

```
total 298
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop    375 ago 13 00:37 CLOSE.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   1015 ago 13 00:37 CommandsHandler.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop    296 ago 13 00:37 CONFIG
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   5483 ago 13 00:37 Config.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop 430080 ago 13 00:37 core
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop    886 ago 13 00:37 Error.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   1774 ago 13 00:37 Heartbeating.c
drwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   4096 ago 13 00:37 inc
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop    346 ago 13 00:37 makefile
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   5530 ago 13 00:37 OPE.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop      0 ago 13 00:37 output.txt
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   3157 ago 13 00:37 READ.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop     37 ago 13 00:37 Run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 federicop federicop  47486 ago 13 08:21 Server
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   3323 ago 13 00:37 server.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   7218 ago 13 00:37 StruttureDati.c
drwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop      0 ago 13 00:37 TestDIR
-rwxrw-rw- 1 federicop federicop   2186 ago 13 00:37 Utils.c
```

I need to run Server, and my user is federicop. This directory is in /media/federicop/Data and i have this line in my fstab:

```
UUID=82440D36440D2F0B /media/federicop/Data ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
```

If i try to run it i get an error:

```
./Server
bash: ./Server: Permission denied
```

The code works in another machine. Also I think is worth mentioning that my files are listed with another color:
[image]

Comment: The color is due to the files being marked executable (see x in permissions section). This behaviour is normal as NTFS does not support the executable option, so the permission is set while mounting depending on umask settings (and standard behaviour will lead to all files marked executable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your NTFS volume is mounted with option `noexec`, which is the default enforced by `permissions`.  See `man ntfs-3g` for details.

You could selectively enable `exec` option by adding it to `fstab`.

```
UUID=82440D36440D2F0B /media/federicop/Data ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions,exec 0 0
```

Run `grep /media/federicop/Data /proc/mounts` to know mount options actually applied.